# Does the empty set need to be explicitly listed as an element of a sigma field?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

When enumerating the sigma fields that can be generated by a set $X$, does the empty set need to be explicitly listed as an element of each of the sigma fields or do the facts that $X$ is an element of each sigma field and that sigma fields are closed under complementation imply that the empty set is a part of each sigma field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on the set $X$. $\Sigma$ is non-empty and so there is some $A\in\Sigma$ hence $X\setminus A$ is also in $\Sigma$. The union of these two sets is $X$ and so $X$ is in $\Sigma$. Finally, $\emptyset=X\setminus X$ is in $\Sigma$ and so $\emptyset\in\Sigma$.

This holds for any $\sigma$-algebra and so you do not have to state that the empty set is in $\Sigma$ in general, unless you are being asked to list every element in the $\sigma$-algebra. It can certainly be omitted from a generating set though.